# modelamiento de base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, model

tengo el siguiente diagrama,[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo 2 preguntas.

1) un usuario tiene variables, estas variables son tiempos, errores y otros, para que sea flexible el cambio, deberia crear otra tabla intermedia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) un usuario tiene errores y tiempos, pero tiene diferentes tiempos, (tiene 3 tiempos) debería crear 3 tablas? para los 3 tiempos o para diferenciarlos esta bien que me base en el atributo `variableB`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cómo se relacionan actualmente la tabla usuario con errores y tiempos?, tienes una columna `id_error` y otra  `id_tiempo` en la tabla `usuario`?

Comment: @Lamak  actualmente esta como en la primer imagen, id_usuario esta en  la tabla tiempos y errores

Comment: @Lamak esos 3 tiempos son, tiempo de realce, tiempo de presion, tiempo entre teclas cuando un usuario escribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que describes, el primer esquema está bien, excepto porque tus tablas de tiempos y errores debiesen tener un `id_usuario` que fuese llave foránea (ya que un tiempo o un error no pueden pertenecer a nadie).

No necesitas una tabla intermedia. Si tuvieras el campo que te digo, y quisieras recuperar los tiempos del usuario 1:

```
SELECT usuario.id_u, usuario.nombre, errores.*
FROM usuario JOIN errores on usuario.id_u = errores.id_usuario
```

Y lo mismo con los tiempos.

Ahora bien, si la variedad de tiempos es limitada, y quieres normalizar tu modelo, entonces la estructura de la tabla tiempos debiese ser

```
id_t  | id_tipo_tiempo | valor_tiempo
```

Y tener una tabla diccionario que tradujera el id_tipo_tiempo a su valor en texto.

```
id_tipo_tiempo   nombre_tiempo
1                tiempo de presion
2                tiempo de realce
3                tiempo entre teclas
```

Esto último es una normalización que probablemente no sea necesaria si estás haciendo sólo una prueba de concepto.